# Show the range of operator is a proper dense subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$
\text { Define an operator } B: \ell^{1} \rightarrow \ell^{1} \text { by }
$
$$
B x=\left(\frac{x_{k}}{k}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=\left(x_{1}, \frac{x_{2}}{2}, \frac{x_{3}}{3}, \ldots\right), \quad \text { for } x=\left(x_{k}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{1}
$$
I want to show range$(B)$ is is a proper dense subspace of $\ell^1$, but not closed.

The proper part is simple since $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not in range$(B)$.

For the dense part, I'm trying to use the fact that $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is in range$(B)$ and hence it's dense, is that correct? Also how to show the closed part? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the dense part, you're correct.

For the not-closed part, you pretty much have it too. You've already observed that $x=\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not in the range of $B$. But note that all elements of the form $\left(1,\frac{1}{2^2},\ldots,\frac{1}{k^2},0,0,\ldots\right)$ are, and their limit is $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If a proper subset is dense  it can never be closed. This  is true for any topological space and it is not special to  $\ell^{1}$.